# Laravel 4 - NotFoundHttpException only for NEW Routes

Tags: php, laravel, lamp, bitnami

I've picked up a project that was developed using Laravel 4.2. I've deployed it to my testing server (a Bitnami LAMP) and everything works as it's supposed to. HOWEVER, **new routes** that I create don't work, getting the error **NotFoundHttpException**.

I've gone through a few recommendations, but nothing has been successful thus far.

Any thoughts or ideas??

Thanks!

--

Just to clarify, any **NEW** route throws the same Not Found error. Even the simplest one like:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    return "This is a test";
});
```

It seems like Laravel is only serving an old version of the Routes.php, is this even possible???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by recreating the project using Laravel 5 instead.